# CIFilters values

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there a cheat list showing all CIFilters and their respective range of values?

How can Apple get away writing a [doc like this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBoxBlur) listing all filters without telling us the possible ranges?

C'mon Apple.

Comment: I know of no such list, but you could always write a program to iterate over the installed CIFilters and print out their min/max ranges. As for the docs, file a bug about it and it will likely get fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated it to work correctly for what I was attempting to show you. I had forgotten that attributes are per filter, and each input key is the name of a key in the attributes dictionary. The values are themselves dictionaries containing the info we want.

Note however, that this doesn't do all the work. You will have to look up a few things if you want more info and do some work on your own. What this does is iterates through all parameters of all filters and prints out the name, min, and max of them, even if that doesn't make sense. (For example images don't have a min or max - in that case it prints "(null)".) Note that many parameters have no min or max. They can cover the entire floating point range. If you're trying to make a slider, use the `kCIAttributeSliderMin` and `kCIAttributeSilderMax` attributes instead of `kCIAttributeMin` and `kCIAttributeMax`.

You could also get the attribute type and class and print out the ranges for other types of values (if that makes sense). For example, some parameters are points, rectangles, etc.

```
// Insert code here to initialize your application
// Get the list of all filters
NSArray* allFilters = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategories:nil];

// Iterate over the filters
NSEnumerator* filterEnum = [allFilters objectEnumerator];
NSString* nextFilter = nil;
while ((nextFilter = [filterEnum nextObject]) != nil)
{
    NSLog (@"filter = %@", nextFilter);
    // Get all of the input parameters to this filter
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:nextFilter]; // 3
    NSDictionary* attribs = [filter attributes];
    NSArray* inputs = [filter inputKeys];

    // Iterate over the input keys
    NSEnumerator* inputEnum = [inputs objectEnumerator];
    NSString* nextInput = nil;
    while ((nextInput = [inputEnum nextObject]) != nil)
    {
        // Note that you'll have to do some work here because some
        // parameters return vectors instead of just numbers, but
        // this is the general idea
        NSDictionary*   paramAttrib = [attribs objectForKey:nextInput];
        NSString* name = [paramAttrib objectForKey:kCIAttributeDisplayName];
        NSNumber* min = [paramAttrib objectForKey:kCIAttributeMin];
        NSNumber* max = [paramAttrib objectForKey:kCIAttributeMax];
        NSLog (@"param: %@, min = %@, max = %@", name, min, max);
    }
}
```

Also, I was serious about filing bugs on the docs. If you don't file bugs, they certainly won't change them. I have filed bugs on documentation and they have gotten fixed.

Comment: code is crashing on NSArray* inputs = [nextFilter inputKeys];  with this error [__NSCFConstantString inputKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: I have corrected a bug on the first part of your code... now it is crashing on the second while

Comment: the line NSArray* inputs = [filter inputKeys]; is returning an array of strings. On the second loop you are using objectForKey on a string and this what is crashing. The object is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: Sorry - I missed a step. The input keys are the names of the parameters. you then have to call `[filter attributes:inputKey]` to get the dictionary. I'll update the code. But please read through the docs of the various methods I've listed here. You seem to be expecting me to just write your code for you.

Comment: On the second loop you are iterating over a list of strings that represent the filter's input keys. The second array does not contains a dictionary as you think.

Comment: This is what is being printed for all filters:  param: (null), min = 0.000000, max = 0.000000

Comment: *You seem to be expecting me to just write your code for you.* this is what happens when someone answers a question. If I knew the answer I would not have ask it here... :(

Comment: @RubberDuck I've updated the code to pull the attributes from the right place. It now works as I originally intended. Please see the [CIFilter docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for any additional changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all filters and their attributes in [this](https://github.com/ilkayaktas/CoreImageFilters) project. It's very useful to understand the detail of filters.

[image]